# Restrict inputText value to alphabetic characters only

Tags: regex, jsf-2, input, primefaces

I need to allow only alphabetic characters `[A-Z,a-z]` in a PrimeFaces inputText field.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14):

Not specific to Primefaces but to underlying JSF:

You can use a regex validator on your input field:

```html
   <h:inputText value="#{myBean.myText}" >
     <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
   </h:inputText>
```

This will work with `p:inputText` as well.

Adapt the regular expression to your functional requirements.

Comment: how to changed regex message? currently it is showing 'Regex pattern does not match'. @Matt Handy

Comment: done with validatorMessage="Alpha numaric characters are not allowed in Last Name." property of inputbox.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to avoid characters in the view (input text) you can user p:keyFilter tag as below

```
<p:inputText id="apePat" 
            placeholder="Apellido Paterno" 
            value="#{actualizaDatos.user.apePat}" 
            autocomplete="off" 
            label="Apellido Paterno" 
            validatorMessage="El campo apellido paterno es requerido">

            <f:validateRequired/>

            <p:keyFilter regEx="/[a-zA-ZÀ-ú\\s\\' ]+/"/>

</p:inputText>
```

Comment: Range À-ú not includes some "regular" alphabetic characters as 'ů' or 'ž' but includes two non alphabetic - ÷ (c3b7) and × (c397)